# Error message in diagnostic plots of GLM in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, diagnostic

I created a generalised linear model in R:

```
mod10 <- glm(RRBEE ~ SNH3000 + PAG1000 + SR250 + C250 + HE250, 
             data = data1, family = poisson)
```

I used the function:

```
plot(mod10)
```

To show the diagnostic plots for the model and it came up with the following error in the console window:

```
Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(crit * p * (1 - hh)/hh) : NaNs produced
2: In sqrt(crit * p * (1 - hh)/hh) : NaNs produced
```

Any suggestions?

For readers who are not `R` users, typically the diagnostic plots include these options:

```
Deviance Residuals vs. Predicted Values,
Response vs. Fitted Values,
Normal QQ Plot of Modified Pearson Residuals,
Normal QQ Plot of Modified Deviance Residuals,
Modified Pearson Residuals vs. Leverage,
Scale-Location.
```

Comment: +1 I think there may be a statistical puzzle here that might interest readers.

Comment: Since there is no plot method for class `glm` and a `glm` object also inherits class `lm` the method that returns this error is `stats:::plot.lm`. The code that throws this error produces the "Residuals vs Leverage" plot and more specifically the "Cook's distance lines". `NaN` values can only be produced if `hh` contains a value > 1. After looking at the code I believe this can only happen if both the minimum value of the diagonal of the hat matrix is > 1 and its maximum value is > 100. It would be nice if you could provide a reproducible example.